# Validation using clean method in models.Model Django

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

If the category is "car" then I would like the x field to be blank, can't has any value.

I try to use the clean method to validate fields so if the category equals to "cars" then the x field should't be entered. I tried something like this below, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.clean()
        return super(Product, self).save(**kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        if self.category == "cars" and self.x is not None:
            raise ValidationError(
                _('information'))

    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default='cars')
    x = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=X_OPTIONS, blank=True)
```

When I am sending `category: "cars", x: "sth",` it doesn't send a clearly json information back to client. It just shows the information on django console with traceback.

Answer (score 2):

Django's `ValidationError` class does not return JSON responses. You either:

1. Move your validation logic to your serializer and have the validation logic throw DRF's `ValidationError` class. See [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation).

```py
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # ...

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        # ...

    def validate(self, data):
        if not data["x"] and data["category"] == "cars":
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                _("information")
            )
        return data
```

2. Implement a custom error handler to intercept Django's `ValidationError` and return an HTTP response. See [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling).

```py
# myapp/api/exceptions.py

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
from rest_framework.response import Response

def django_error_handler(exc, context):
    """Handle django core's errors."""
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    if response is None and isinstance(exc, ValidationError):
        return Response(status=400, data=exc.message_dict)
    return response


# settings.py

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # ...
    "EXCEPTION_HANDLER": "myapp.api.exceptions.django_error_handler",
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have ```if not self.category and self.category == "cars":``` condition, I have ```if self.category == "cars" and self.x is not None:```. How can I get the self.x field too and validate it at the same time?

Comment: @somenoobyquestions oops, thats completely my fault for misreading the code. I have updated the answer. Cheers.